# PHP app on the host could not connect Mariadb on Docker container

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mariadb

I have PHP application that deployed on Apache server on my Ubuntu computer. Also I have docker installed on that machine and it runs Mariadb container. The Mariadb container's IP is `172.19.0.2` When I try to run my app using the following data, I get **`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '172.19.0.2'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'factory2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'passWrd!'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true, //true
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

The following is `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
a9238ccdb033   redis          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   59 minutes ago   Up 59 minutes   6379/tcp                                redis
eaf7a2d65c28   phpmyadmin     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 days ago       Up 35 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   myadmin
b3a247a8cb50   mariadb:10.5   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago       Up 35 minutes   3306/tcp                                mariadb
```

While the following is `docker inspect mariadb`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "b3a247a8cb5048feca4f210215cf75424699a2459e330e21b0faf9c0228d7649",
        "Created": "2021-12-09T22:49:46.738427197Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 19043,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-12-14T19:34:34.91380238Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2021-12-13T15:21:02.934212265Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9a0e59bdf6f04475b9c3b17dd48dd9da27860cbba9ef57ed7c6b0b0d3d462a31",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b3a247a8cb5048feca4f210215cf75424699a2459e330e21b0faf9c0228d7649/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b3a247a8cb5048feca4f210215cf75424699a2459e330e21b0faf9c0228d7649/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b3a247a8cb5048feca4f210215cf75424699a2459e330e21b0faf9c0228d7649/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/b3a247a8cb5048feca4f210215cf75424699a2459e330e21b0faf9c0228d7649/b3a247a8cb5048feca4f210215cf75424699a2459e330e21b0faf9c0228d7649-json.log",
        "Name": "/mariadb",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "foxNet",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb6654076293bb60b2e85685649fb1a5a8c1eaf2bba79ccf30a456a414a21bac-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f596fbc9a0d431c1932c86c403ff9e6ed0d2e7946fd9c16cec6774dfbadf4cf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f13260954b0ba2f91d647a35c83a50c65911f4c2229abcfdf233a1766064d52/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f0bca67612beb8f65c2e3f1d72f6a6e44b14e94153bda51f24858dee7ca9804b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5cef85dc663f01eb2fe78a1c79927a81fc4ad95cc60c2520ccf863f4a0fbac4e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ebe2589fb1d5ea1b2802dc6dd03c65a22084525f07a854c0c1e78b838294982/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a1a9f9de66b0d397328ac4ad238abc32e0de54f8fd6f85348a9a0d5001a6e1e4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c62348dea983800c6521fa0bf2d468855bcd46a8879356e79227a845941b9e10/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8af423b9712cd9f60ce3d6d036170d68a7ddbbfcbebe9cc56f78335a5818a82b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7d045b063959f602c3952569deaf115b84e1d6597a8b53122e0375b1c8b883d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b50040f8f698cecc0d626da4fc45a3a6c9019c8d10d991b73e1485847cf41ecd/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb6654076293bb60b2e85685649fb1a5a8c1eaf2bba79ccf30a456a414a21bac/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb6654076293bb60b2e85685649fb1a5a8c1eaf2bba79ccf30a456a414a21bac/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb6654076293bb60b2e85685649fb1a5a8c1eaf2bba79ccf30a456a414a21bac/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "c5bdddd18207dbe7a4f1d99d0eadff4c37d60fcdec159015c772bf5c61342ce9",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/c5bdddd18207dbe7a4f1d99d0eadff4c37d60fcdec159015c772bf5c61342ce9/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "b3a247a8cb50",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MARIADB_USER=said",
                "MARIADB_PASSWORD=passWrd!",
                "MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=passWrd!",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.14",
                "MARIADB_MAJOR=10.5",
                "MARIADB_VERSION=1:10.5.13+maria~focal"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "Image": "mariadb:10.5",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "e84b620edfd4ae00ae588f4b02a31965d4063c4c1271b6ae6dd8c1cac09c49f0",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e84b620edfd4",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "foxNet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "b3a247a8cb50"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "1e3427aacb8ffb79404adfecfc63a51e6da994bc3ff9988a4c66bcf647f82e63",
                    "EndpointID": "caba35311ad6c3b521fcbd0cff3aedb013e3b61d39324a93ee698fd167281259",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: `172.19.0.2` is the IP inside the docker network, this is not exposed to your host. https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Well, could I modify the container without loss its data by running new container?

Comment: Depends on how you are running your container, which you did not show here. If you used [a proper volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) where needed, then yes, otherwise, no.

Comment: #1 Are you able to connect to mariadb without php? Just to validate that mariadb is ok. #2 Use [host.docker.internal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207679/3957754) #3 Keep in mind that docker-compose is just for test o very limited production environment. Anyway [export](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/1552426802d46e0f7dd06b9dde1101c1) your data an recreate the mysql db is easy